# (Swift) pan & zoom constrained to a certain size image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to pan and zoom across an image background in spritekit, I have managed to get the zoom working ok and manually entered some restrictions on how far you can pan the image, however the problem is when you pan the screen right to the edge of the image and then zoom out the background shows. 
I want the camera to restrict only to the image on screen and not any blank background. Any ideas on how I should do this or any better solutions?
Here is what I got so far

```
class GameScene:SKScene{
 var cam: SKCameraNode!
 var scaleNum:CGFloat=1

 override func didMove(to view: SKView){
    cam=SKCameraNode()
    cam.setScale(CGFloat(scaleNum))
    self.camera=cam
    self.addChild(cam)  
    let gesture=UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(zoomIn(recognizer:)))
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func zoomIn(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    if recognizer.state == .changed{
        cam.setScale(recognizer.scale)
        scaleNum=recognizer.scale
        if cam.xScale<1 || cam.yScale<1{
            cam.setScale(1)
        }
        if cam.xScale>3 || cam.yScale > 3{
            cam.setScale(3)
       }
       // recognizer.scale=1
       test()
    }
}

 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   let firstTouch=touches.first
        let location=(firstTouch?.location(in: self))!
        let previousLocation=firstTouch?.previousLocation(in: self)
        cam?.position.x -= location.x - (previousLocation?.x)!
        cam?.position.y -= location.y - (previousLocation?.y)!
        test()
}

func test(){
    if cam.position.x < 1000*scaleNum{
        cam.position.x=1000*scaleNum
    }
    if cam.position.x > 9200*scaleNum{
        cam.position.x=9200*scaleNum
    }
    if cam.position.y<617*scaleNum{
        cam.position.y=617*scaleNum
    }
    if cam.position.y>4476*scaleNum{
        cam.position.y=4476*scaleNum
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer above, I managed to get it working, code below. Still needs a bit of tweaking but you can pan and zoom anywhere on the background image but the view should be constrained within the background image and not move into empty space beyond the image

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var cam: SKCameraNode!
    var scaleNum: CGFloat=1
    var background: SKSpriteNode!
    var playableRect: CGRect!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        background=self.childNode(withName: "clouds") as! SKSpriteNode
        cam=SKCameraNode()
        cam.setScale(CGFloat(scaleNum))
        self.camera=cam
        self.addChild(cam)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
        let gesture=UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(zoomIn(recognizer:)))
        self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        let maxAspectRatio:CGFloat=16.0/9.0
        let playableHeight=size.width/maxAspectRatio
        let playableMargin=(size.height-playableHeight)/2.0
        playableRect=CGRect(x:0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)
    }

    func zoomIn(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        if recognizer.state == .changed{
            let savedScale=scaleNum
            scaleNum=recognizer.scale
            if scaleNum<1{
                scaleNum=1
            }
            else if scaleNum>3{
                scaleNum=3
            }
            if testcamera(posX: cam.position.x, posY: cam.position.y){
                cam.setScale(scaleNum)
            }
            else{
                scaleNum=savedScale
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let firstTouch=touches.first
        let location=(firstTouch?.location(in: self))!
        var posX=cam.position.x
        var posY=cam.position.y
        let previousLocation=firstTouch?.previousLocation(in: self)
        posX -= location.x - (previousLocation?.x)!
        posY -= location.y - (previousLocation?.y)!
        if testcamera(posX: posX, posY: posY){
            cam.position.x=posX
            cam.position.y=posY
        }

    }

    func testcamera(posX: CGFloat, posY: CGFloat)->Bool{
        var cameraRect : CGRect {
            let xx = posX - size.width/2*scaleNum
            let yy = posY - playableRect.height/2*scaleNum
            return CGRect(x: xx, y: yy, width: size.width*scaleNum, height: playableRect.height*scaleNum)
        }
        let backGroundRect=CGRect(x: background.position.x-background.frame.width/2, y: background.position.y-background.frame.height/2, width: background.frame.width, height: background.frame.height)
        return backGroundRect.contains(cameraRect)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would change your `zoomIn` function to this:

```
func zoomIn(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
   if recognizer.state == .changed {
       scaleNum = recognizer.scale
       if scaleNum < 1 { scaleNum = 1 }
       if scaleNum > 3 { scaleNum = 3 }
       cam.setScale(scaleNum)
       test()
   }
}
```

It is easier to understand, you're not setting the camera scale twice, and most importantly, when you clamp the camera scale, `scaleNum` reflects that clamped value.  This was not the case before, and in fact, that small change might be your entire problem.

Now I don't have much experience with `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` but I think the reason your zoom gesture works "ok" is because you are assigning directly from `recognizer.scale` to `cam` scale.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `UIGestureRecognizer` always starts with a scale of 1 for each new gesture, but your camera scale maintains its last value.

As an example, imagine your camera is at a scale of 1. A user zooms in to a scale of 2, the scene zooms in perfectly.  The user lifts their fingers ending the gesture.  Then the user tries to zoom in more, so they begin a new gesture, starting with a scale of 1, but your scene is still at a scale of 2.  You can't assign the gesture scale directly or the image scale will 'jump' back to 1 for each new gesture.  You have to convert from the gesture scale space to the camera scale space.

How exactly you do this is a design and feel choice.  With no experience, my advice would be to change the line in my `zoomIn` function from

```
`scaleNum = recognizer.scale'
```

to

```
`scaleNum *= recognizer.scale`
```

Try both versions, and let me know how they work.  If there is still a problem, then it most likely resides in your `test()` function.  If so, I will try and help out with that as needed.